# Accessing text of span element embedded within another span element

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i would like to get contents of all those span elements and put them into a dictionary.
I am only able to access the first span element using the following code:
Is there a way to do it ? Maybe selenium a better option ?

```
<span class="font-size-15" style="vertical-align:top"><strong>Title of the 
product</strong></span>
<span>Seller: Staples </span>
<span>Description: Here you will find the product description</span>
```

MY CODE

```
page_source=BeautifulSoup(page_source,"html.parser")
products = page_source.findAll("span"})

for product in products:
    product_name=product.span.text
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html code above there are no spans embedded in others, so it would be enough to iterate through the products and keep the text contents of them in a dictionary like this:

```
dic = {}
i = 0
for product in products:
    dic[i] = product.getText()
    i += 1

print(dic)
```

But supposing there would be embedded spans in each span, then you use the findAll method again on the element just like this:

```
dic = {}
i = 0
for product in products:
    spans = prodcut.findAll("span")
    for span in spans:
        dic[i] = span.getText()
        i += 1

print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `select`.You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<span class="font-size-15" style="vertical-align:top"><strong>Title of the 
product</strong></span>
<span>Seller: Staples </span>
<span>Description: Here you will find the product description</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

spans = soup.select('span')

dic = {}
i = 1
for span in spans:
    dic[i] = span.text
    i = i + 1

print(dic)
```

Ooutput will be:

```
{1: 'Title of the \nproduct', 2: 'Seller: Staples ', 3: 'Description: Here you will find the product description'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. My followup question is how do i traverse the dictionary to diplay:   "title, seller description"  as collumns titles and then the products under them

Comment: @JotkanwalSingh Glad to help out, please consider to upvote and/or accept if it helped. [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)